# Setting breakpoints in a Java gradle project in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I have a Java gradle project in Intellij that I want to debug using breakpoints. When I press the green run button, everything runs fine. When I press the debug button, it still runs fine, but no breakpoints get hit. My run configuration looks like this:

[image: My gradle project]

[image: My debug configuration]

I also tried setting the project to build and run using Intellij IDEA like this, but this did not help either (it also does not work when I select "gradle"):

[image: Build and run using intellij IDEA]

What steps are needed to fix this? The last questions on this topic unfortunately did not manage to solve this problem.

I work with Intellij 2021.1.2 and gradle 6.8.

Comment: What about using a normal java run configuration instead of executing a gradle target?

Comment: @dan1st When I run the central core.main() function directly in intellij with a right click, then I get a Nullpointerexception (something internal like "Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()"...) that I cannot really debug because it is not my project. (I hope I didn't misunderstand your suggestion.)

Comment: But if you run gradle, you would debug gradle and not your program. You might want to fix the NullPointerException first so you can debug properly.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have hard time debugging the app and fixing the NPE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder So did I understand this correctly: the main function in a Java program should be able to run flawlessly when started normally (in my case it's a Swing program), and it is a bug if it only works when you start it with "gradlew run"?

Comment: It depends on the project. I can imagine configurations where the app will work via Gradle, but not directly via IDE, though it's rare and usually involves some complex build scripts or Gradle plug-ins unsupported by the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments posted by dan1st and CrazyCoder, what I was trying to do was not a good idea and it is better to debug the java project directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling the "Debug all tasks on the execution graph" option? This help me to get debugging to work correctly

Comment: Unfortunately this also did not work (=same behaviour as before).